# VBScript Invalid Character 800A0408 error

Tags: vbscript

After much searching, I have not been able to find a solution to the error. This script is used to find corrupt cache files in the c:\Windows\Installer directory

this is the offending line of code:

```
Log "Debug: Found " & dicSUpdatesAll.Count – iCnt & " unique patch(es) in folder " & Folder
```

the full script can be found here [gist](https://gist.github.com/jwstl/0240b284ecf7049731294e53587f4bc5)

[image: the error message]

Comment: The character at position 44 in that line is the `–` which is not the same as `-` (the second one is the one you want and need)

Comment: More specifically, you're using an [en-dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash) where you need a [hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen). I recommend avoiding typographic character substitutions in source code like the plague.

Comment: thank you for all of the suggestions, I was able to solve that specific error, and a dozen more. the gist has been updated with the final code for reference.